# Changing the authentication procedure in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2

I have modified the postLogin() method in my authController.php.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
          $inputs = $request->all();

          $this->validateLogin($request);

          // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
          // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
          // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
          $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

          if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
              $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

              return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
          }

          $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

          if ($inputs['email'] == 'test@test.com') {
              return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
          }

          // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
          // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
          // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
          if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
              $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
          }

          return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);

    }
```

Now if I enter something different than test@test.com in the email form, I get back to the login page with the error this user is not recognised. But if I use the correct email test@test.com, then I can see it goes to the correct page (redirect is working) and then back to the login page as if I am not authenticated.

I suppose this is because it doesn't setup cookies or something like this stating to Laravel that the user is authenticated for good.

What I try to achieve is this:
in fact I would like to change the way I authenticate and make a request to my company active directory with username password and it will send me back true or false. That way I don't need to use the local database to store passwords. So it needs to check first that the email is in the local database then it will connect via curl to the AD of my company and will get a response then I will know if user has entered the correct password.

Comment: Check your middle ware is there correct way to auth check?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually authenticate the user. Take a look at this sample code:

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials) {
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
} else {
    return redirect($this->loginPath()) // login route
        ->withInput($request->only('email'))
        ->withErrors([
            'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

Also, what are you trying to achieve with this? Do you want to bypass authentication with a test@test.com user for testing purpose? I'd recommend you to create a new user (within [`php artisan tinker`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#introduction) or something) for this.

However, if you want to authenticate your users only by their e-mail, you'll need to overwrite the `validateLogin` method to only validate the `email` input, and the `getCredentials` method to only get the `email` from `$request`.

Comment: No, in fact I would like to change the way I authenticate and make a request to my company active directory with username password and it will send me back true or false. That way I don't need to use the local database to store passwords. So it needs to check first that the email is in the local database then it will connect via curl to the AD of my company and will get a response then I will know if user has entered the correct password.